# How to query between multiple APIs with VueJS?

Tags: vuejs2

I need some help on how to approach the logic for my single page app with VueJS. This is difficult for me to explain, so I hope I can do my best:

I have a template/component with one API GET request via Axios like so:

> Component named "Similar Entities"

```
<template>
    <div v-if='gde.length > 0'>
        <h4>Similar Entitie(s)</h4>
      <ul>
        <li v-for='item in gde'>
            <a href='#'>{{item['Similar Entities']}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import api from '@/api.js';

export default {
  name: 'SimilarEntities',
  data: function() {
    return {
      gde: []
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    axios
      .get(api.getSimilarEntities + this.$route.params.ID)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.gde = response.data;
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

The above template returns HTML with a bullet list like so:

- **Building**
- **Hardened Aircraft Shelter**

(and the `gde` object looks like this)

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":100,
      "Name":"Aircraft Hangar",
      "Similar Entities":"Building"
   },
   {  
      "ID":100,
      "Name":"Aircraft Hangar",
      "Similar Entities":"Hardened Aircraft Shelter"
   }
]
```

The above 'Similar Entities' component is part of a larger template (which is part of a larger template!) which uses another Axios.get request to populate a product details page like so:

> Component named 'Appearance'

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
       <p>INfo about this product</p>
        <ul>
        <li v-for='item in ga'></li>
        </ul>
        <similar-entities></similar-entities>
       </div>

      </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import api from '@/api.js';
import SimilarEntities from '@/components/SimilarEntities.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Appearance',
  components: {
    SimilarEntities
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      ga: []
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    axios
      .get(api.getAppearance + this.$route.params.ID)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.ga = response.data;
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

The above 'Appearance' template returns HTML like so:

**Appearance**

**An aircraft hangar is a place where aircraft are stored....blah blah blah**

**- Building**

**- Hardened Aircraft Shelter**

Overall, the $route.params object for the single page component with router info is like so:

```
   {  
      "ID":100,
      "Name":"Aircraft Hangar"
   }
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to hyperlink the Similar Entities items in the Similar Entities component (in this case, `Building` and `Hardened Aircraft Shelter`) to their respective product details page because they do not contain their associated IDs.

*Note: There is an endpoint available that I can use called `getNames` which contains the product names for all of the products (including the name of our `Building` and `Hardened Aircraft Shelter` products) that contains the following data:*

```
{  
      "ID":100,
      "Name":"Aircraft Hangar"
},
{
      "ID": 101,
      "Name": "Building"
},
{
       "ID": 102,
       "Name": "Carport"
}
...snip
```

Should I put the `getNames` api in some kind of global state? Then with the $route.params object I can grab the key named `Name` and then somehow look at the global state of the `getNames` object and dynamically bind the Name to the hyperlink element of the Similar Entities component? This way, the `Building` and `Hardened Aircraft Shelter` links in the `Similar Entities` component gets linked ? All I am trying to do is get the user to the correct product page when they click on a `Similar Entities` link (in this demo, it's `Building` or `Hardened Aircraft Shelter`).

Thanks for any tips. I am probably overthinking this....

Comment: How does your `this.ga` array look like? can you post that as wll

Comment: Also can't this be possible `<a :href="'product/'+item.id">{{item['Similar Entities']}}</a>` redirecting to proper product page?

Comment: It seems that API is flawed. Can you alter it?